# Analyze a video, look for a colored pixel or logo

Tags: python, video-processing

I want to sift through a collection of video files looking for a certain logo, and then record the 10-15 seconds leading up to it. I can recognize the logo by checking a certain pixel color.

How would you do it? Is there software or a python package that allows me to extract those chunks of files and write those into a new video?

What i have done so far: 
I have found a library that is able to convert a video into a series of BMPs. What the programs. Its called pyMedia: http://pymedia.org/tut/src/dump_video.py.html and the reverse: http://pymedia.org/tut/src/make_video.py.html
So thats pretty neat. However its only working with python 2.3, not with python 3.

Seems like :

```
d= e.encode( yuvFrame )
fw.write( d )
```

writes a BMP file. So how do i look in for a certain colored pixel or logo  in a BMP file and put it together? Thats what i cant get working somehow. Maybe someone can help me with this.

edit:
let me show you what i have done so far:

```
from PIL import Image
im = Image.open("bride.bmp")
i=0
width= 10
height = 10
top= 461
box = (left, top, left+width, top+height)
croppy=im.crop(box)
if (mycolor in croppy.getcolors()):
        print "Logo found"
```

My logo has a certain color, so this looks for the pixel and prints logo found if the pixelcolor is found. Didnt really want to make a classifier for that.

Answer (score 1):

Using perhaps OpenCV or another package -- essentially, you want to train a classifier to identify your logo and then feed it the bitmaps from your video. When it identifies the logo, then you trigger the code which captures the previous 15s of video.

This is a very detailed answer about how one might do this in Python [General approach to developing an image classification algorithm for Dilbert cartoons](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8108550/general-approach-to-developing-an-image-classification-algorithm-for-dilbert-car)